# Verify which MDS.stg table is related to which MDS model for SSIS data load

Tags: ssis, master-data-services

I need to load the data into the MDS staging tables by using SSIS.

The problem is that there are many MDS models, and every one of them has its own staging tables, but they are not named properly (by using `model_name.stgTable` scheme). They just have numbers at the end.

Could you tell me how to verify which `MDS.stg` table is related to which MDS model?

Example (staging Status tables for different MDS models):

[image]